# R lubridate package installation - Error in as.POSIXlt

Tags: r, lubridate

I am trying to install the package lubridate of R but I have always the same error message. 
Looking around it looks related to the fact that it has a function date() which already exist
also as base::date(). But during the test of the package it calls date() and therefore the error.

Here what I get:

```
install.packages("lubridate")
Installing package into ‘/home/user/R/i586-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/lubridate_1.6.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'unknown' length 317672 bytes (310 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 310 KB

* installing *source* package ‘lubridate’ ...
** package ‘lubridate’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
installing to /home/user/R/i586-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/lubridate/libs
** R
** data
*** moving datasets to lazyload DB
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded
Error in as.POSIXlt(x, tz = tz(x)) : 
  argument "x" is missing, with no default
Calls: .Last -> cat -> paste -> date -> date.default -> as.POSIXlt
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
* removing ‘/home/user/R/i586-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/lubridate’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘lubridate’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpuzZ3SK/downloaded_packages’
```

Here my sessionInfo():

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.3 (2017-03-06)
Platform: i586-pc-linux-gnu (32-bit)
Running under: Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_GB.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_GB.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_GB.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_GB.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_GB.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_GB.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_GB.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] graphics  grDevices utils     methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.3.3
```

Any idea how to avoid this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved.

It was just because the line

> cat(paste(date(),"\nAdios\n"))

in the file:

> ~/.Rprofile

One has to remove the call to date() in ~/.Rprofile.

For details see:
https://github.com/business-science/tidyquant/issues/62